# Error Loading Static Fragment and a FrameLayout (

Tags: android, android-fragments, layout, static

I'm trying to load layout with a static fragment and a LinearLayout using this Layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
    tools:context="com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs.MainActivity">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment"
        android:name="com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs.MainActivityFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/movies_detail_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="4" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But when the app is launched I get this error:

```
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: ModernAsyncTask #2
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs, PID: 13809
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$3.done(ModernAsyncTask.java:142)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1437)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:462)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompatJellybean.query(ContentResolverCompatJellybean.java:29)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat$ContentResolverCompatImplJB.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:57)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ContentResolverCompat.query(ContentResolverCompat.java:125)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:59)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:37)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:296)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:54)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:42)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.content.ModernAsyncTask$2.call(ModernAsyncTask.java:128)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
11-02 23:02:36.418 13809-13880/com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

The same Activity and fragments work when I'm loading them using a layout that contain only the fragment.

any ideas?

The full code is in a GitHub repo - https://github.com/yossildad/PopularMovs
Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the code for your `Loader`?

Comment: Added a link to the code in the main question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace I could see you are trying to get an URI from a null reference in the doInBackground() method in activity com.eldad.yossi.popularmovs.MainActivity .

Comment: I don't use URIs in the MainActivity

Comment: Ok but are you trying to get a scheme of URI either directly or indirectly in your doInBackground() method ?

Comment: No. it was done by the OS while trying to create a CursorLoader

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've found the bug. I was using a not initialized uri when creating the Loader
inside the fragment.
Thanks for your help and sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is not in the fragment declaration. According to the stacktrace, look into the doInBackground method of your ModernASyncTask which you are extends on.
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground() - probably you may have null reference on a context object, i guess.

Comment: I added some debug prints and saw that the crash happens before the doInBackground method is called (or even the Task is created). I think that this is an OS Task.

Comment: it will be much easy to find the problem if your share source code of the loader you use...

Comment: The GitHub repo is - https://github.com/yossildad/PopularMovs. Thank you very much!

Comment: try to double check your  URIs for CursorLoader, seems problem is in static initialization.